# Please have a look at the code, clang is giving the error " incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'string' to parameter type 'int' "

Tags: c, if-statement, char, c-strings, tolower

```
float x;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(tolower(item), tolower(menu[i].item)) == 0)
        {
            x = menu[i].price;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to compare the item and menu[i].item by converting them both into lowercase

Comment: Show the declaration/definition of `menu` and `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using a function always read the function description.

The function `tolower` is declared the following way

```
#include <ctype.h>
int tolower(int c);
```

As you can see it returns an object of the type `int` and in turn accepts integers. But it seems you are passing to the function strings (as character arrays or pointers).

So the compiler issues the message.

Also the function `strcmp` is declared like

```
#include <string.h>
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

That is it expects pointers to char as arguments.

However in this if statement

```
if (strcmp(tolower(item), tolower(menu[i].item)) == 0)
```

instead of passing pointers to strings (to their first characters) to the function `strcmp` you are passing integers returned by the function `tolower`.

It seems you need to write yourself a function that compares two strings characters of which are converted to the low case. For example the function can look the following way

```
int str_tolower_cmp( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    unsigned char c1 = tolower( ( unsigned char )*s1 );
    unsigned char c2 = tolower( ( unsigned char )*s2 );

    while ( c1 &&  c1 == c2 )
    {
        c1 = tolower( ( unsigned char )*++s1 );
        c2 = tolower( ( unsigned char )*++s2 );
    }

    return ( c2 < c1 ) - ( c1 < c2 );
}
```

and then

```
if ( str_tolower_cmp( item, menu[i].item ) == 0 )
//...
```

Otherwise if objects with the name `item` have type `char` then just write

```
if ( tolower(( unsigned char )item) == tolower(( unsigned char )menu[i].item))
```

Or if the variable `item` has type `char` and `menu[i].item` represents a string then you can write

```
if ( tolower(( unsigned char )item) == tolower(( unsigned char )menu[i].item[0]))
```